# Linking css to html asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

The problem is that css is not linking to html. I think I did it correctly (the path to css is also correct). Here is the code:

Index.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Views demo</title>
    <link href="~/Content/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-container">
        <div id="footer">
            <p>
                Copyright &copy; 2019 <a href="http">
                    AAAAA
                    &amp; DDD
                </a>. All rights reserved.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="content-wrap">
            @{
                int i = 6;
            }
            Value: @i
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

StyleSheet.css

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#page-container
{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#content-wrap
{

}
#footer {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #343deb;
    background-color: #004d40;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: What is output you are having currently  and what do you want  it to be?  also did you tried inspecting your html using Inspect Element tool (F12)  that everything is loading up correctly (i.e  the  style you applied to the footer and the css in the html page is loaded correctly )

Comment: the output (on console) is `net::ERR_ABORTED 404`, but the path is correct (I checked this, I "dropped" file from directory tree and I got the same path). Everything work if I declare style inside `.cshtml` file

Answer (score 0):

Your href is wrong. The tilde `~` does not work in a page's header (not needed for links anyway), it is (generally) for server controls, not plain html.

```
<!-- remove the ~. also do not need 'type'. -->
<link href="/Content/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: No difference, I had in the same directory too, but it didn't work. `~` was sugessted by Visual Code.